# Generate all combinations given a constraint

Tags: r, combinations

How can I generate all of the 6 combinations of 2 treatments (A,B) in blocks of 4, such that in each block there is an equal number of A's and B's, using R?

```
"AABB","ABAB","ABBA","BBAA","BABA","BAAB"
```

P.S. The number of combinations is calculated as follows:

If

```
T = #treatments

n = #treatments in each block = k*T,
```

The number of combinations equals `n! / [k!*k! (T times)]`

Thank you

Comment: side query: do you mean the number of combinations is n! /( (k!)^T) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
library(gtools)

t <- c('A','B')
k <- 2
n <- k * length(t)

t2 <- rep(t, k)
m <- permutations(n,n)
res <- unique(apply(m,MARGIN=1,function(x) paste(t2[x],collapse='')))

--------------------------------------------------------------------
res
[1] "ABAB" "ABBA" "AABB" "BAAB" "BABA" "BBAA"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `multicool` package implements an algorithm for permuting multisets --- exactly the task you want to have performed. Here's an example of what it can do:

```
library(multicool)

# Create a simple convenience function
enumAllPartitions <- function(multiset) {
    m1 <-  initMC(multiset)        # Initialize the permutation object
    N <- fact(length(multiset))/   # Calculate number of permutations
         prod(fact(table(multiset)))
    sapply(seq_len(N), function(X) paste(nextPerm(m1), collapse=""))
}

# Try it out with a few different multisets
x <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
y <- c("G", "L", "L", "L")
z <- c("X", "X", "Y", "Z", "Z")

lapply(list(x,y,z), enumAllPartitions)
[[1]]
[1] "BBAA" "ABBA" "BABA" "ABAB" "AABB" "BAAB"

[[2]]
[1] "LLLG" "GLLL" "LGLL" "LLGL"

[[3]]
 [1] "ZZYXX" "XZZYX" "ZXZYX" "ZZXYX" "XZZXY" "ZXZXY" "XZXZY" "XXZZY" "ZXXZY"
[10] "ZZXXY" "YZZXX" "ZYZXX" "XZYZX" "ZXYZX" "YZXZX" "XYZZX" "YXZZX" "ZYXZX"
[19] "XZYXZ" "ZXYXZ" "XZXYZ" "XXZYZ" "ZXXYZ" "YZXXZ" "XYZXZ" "YXZXZ" "XYXZZ"
[28] "XXYZZ" "YXXZZ" "ZYXXZ"
```

Answer (score 1):

The expected solution can also be achieved using the new `iterpc` package.

```
I <- iterpc(c(2, 2), labels=c("A", "B"), ordered=TRUE)
getall(I)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "A"  "A"  "B"  "B" 
# [2,] "A"  "B"  "A"  "B" 
# [3,] "A"  "B"  "B"  "A" 
# [4,] "B"  "A"  "A"  "B" 
# [5,] "B"  "A"  "B"  "A" 
# [6,] "B"  "B"  "A"  "A"
```