# All combinations with multiple constraints

Tags: r

I wish to generate all possible combinations of a set of numbers, but with multiple constraints.  I have found several similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none that appear to address all of my constraints:

[R: sample() command subject to a constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951206/r-sample-command-subject-to-a-constraint)

[R all combinations of 3 vectors with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320766/r-all-combinations-of-3-vectors-with-conditions)

[Generate all combinations given a constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045104/generate-all-combinations-given-a-constraint)

[R - generate all combinations from 2 vectors given constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519836/r-generate-all-combinations-from-2-vectors-given-constraints)

Below is an example data set.  This is a deterministic data set, in my mind anyway.

```
desired.data <- read.table(text = '
     x1  x2  x3  x4
      1   1   1   1
      1   1   1   2
      1   1   1   3
      1   1   2   1
      1   1   2   2
      1   1   2   3
      1   1   3   3
      1   2   1   1
      1   2   1   2
      1   2   1   3
      1   2   2   1
      1   2   2   2
      1   2   2   3
      1   2   3   3
      1   3   3   3
      0   1   1   1
      0   1   1   2
      0   1   1   3
      0   1   2   1
      0   1   2   2
      0   1   2   3
      0   1   3   3
      0   0   1   1
      0   0   1   2
      0   0   1   3
      0   0   0   1
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')
```

Here are the constraints:

1. Column 1 can only contain a 0 or 1
2. The last column can only contain 1, 2 or 3
3. All other columns can contain 0, 1, 2 or 3
4. Once a non-0 appears in a row the rest of that row cannot contain another 0
5. Once a 3 appears in a row the rest of that row must only contain 3's
6. The first non-0 number in a row must be a 1

The only way I know to generate this type of data set is to use nested `for-loops` as shown below.  I have used this technique for years and finally decided to ask if there might be a better way.

I hope this is not a duplicate and I hope it is not considered too specialized.  I create these types of data sets frequently and a simpler solution would be quite helpful.

```
my.data <- matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 25)
my.data <- as.data.frame(my.data)

j <- 1

for(i1 in 0:1) {

     if(i1 == 0) i2.begin = 0
     if(i1 == 0) i2.end   = 1
     if(i1 == 1) i2.begin = 1
     if(i1 == 1) i2.end   = 3
     if(i1 == 2) i2.begin = 1
     if(i1 == 2) i2.end   = 3
     if(i1 == 3) i2.begin = 3
     if(i1 == 3) i2.end   = 3

     for(i2 in i2.begin:i2.end) {

          if(i2 == 0) i3.begin = 0
          if(i2 == 0) i3.end   = 1
          if(i2 == 1) i3.begin = 1
          if(i2 == 1) i3.end   = 3
          if(i2 == 2) i3.begin = 1
          if(i2 == 2) i3.end   = 3
          if(i2 == 3) i3.begin = 3
          if(i2 == 3) i3.end   = 3

          for(i3 in i3.begin:i3.end) {

               if(i3 == 0) i4.begin = 1  # 1 not 0 because last column
               if(i3 == 0) i4.end   = 1
               if(i3 == 1) i4.begin = 1
               if(i3 == 1) i4.end   = 3
               if(i3 == 2) i4.begin = 1
               if(i3 == 2) i4.end   = 3
               if(i3 == 3) i4.begin = 3
               if(i3 == 3) i4.end   = 3

               for(i4 in i4.begin:i4.end) {

                    my.data[j,1] <- i1
                    my.data[j,2] <- i2
                    my.data[j,3] <- i3
                    my.data[j,4] <- i4

                    j <- j + 1

               }
          }
     }
}

my.data
dim(my.data)
```

Here is the output:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1   0  0  0  1
2   0  0  1  1
3   0  0  1  2
4   0  0  1  3
5   0  1  1  1
6   0  1  1  2
7   0  1  1  3
8   0  1  2  1
9   0  1  2  2
10  0  1  2  3
11  0  1  3  3
12  1  1  1  1
13  1  1  1  2
14  1  1  1  3
15  1  1  2  1
16  1  1  2  2
17  1  1  2  3
18  1  1  3  3
19  1  2  1  1
20  1  2  1  2
21  1  2  1  3
22  1  2  2  1
23  1  2  2  2
24  1  2  2  3
25  1  2  3  3
26  1  3  3  3
```

**EDIT**

Sorry that I initially forgot to include Constraint #6.

Comment: @nongkrong  Good point.  I need to add another constraint: that the first non-0 number must be a 1.

Comment: `d <- expand.grid(list(0:1,0:2,0:3,1:3)) ` this covers 1,2, and 3. 4-6, I think you have to do row by row. I couldn't figure out any `diff()` or `cumsum()` magic to pattern after.

Comment: You can improve the efficiency your group of for loops if you just don't convert it to a data.frame before the for loops and assign each row at once like this `my.data[j,1]<-c(i1,i2,i3,i4)`  In your example you'd have to initialize the matrix to 26 rows instead of just 25.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @mrip, start from `expand.grid` which can handle the first 3 constraints since they don't interact with the other columns

```
step1<-expand.grid(0:1,0:3,0:3,1:3)
```

Next I would filter it.  The difference between this approach and mrip's is that my filtering is in one apply instead of 3 so it *should* be around 3 times faster to filter.

```
filtered<-step1[apply(step1,1,function(x) all(if(length(which(x==0))>0) {max(which(x==0))==length(which(x==0))} else {TRUE}, if(length(which(x==3))>0) {min(which(x==3))==length(x)-length(which(x==3))+1} else {TRUE}, x[!x%in%0][1]==1)),]
```

That should be it.  If you want to inspect each element inside the apply here it is:

`if(length(which(x==0))>0) {max(which(x==0))==length(which(x==0))} else {TRUE}`

If there are any zeros then it makes sure that nothing comes before the zero

`if(length(which(x==3))>0) {min(which(x==3))==length(x)-length(which(x==3))+1} else {TRUE}`

If there are any 3s it makes sure nothing is after them.

`x[!x%in%0][1]==1)` This first filters the zeros out of the row and then takes the first element of the row after that filter and only allows it to be a one.

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  Where does `desired.data` come from?  In my post `desired.data` is the answer I hope to obtain.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the variable name is, that's the only name of a variable from your question

Comment: Where do the data come from that are being analyzed in `step1`?  I am asking how to generate a data set given a set of constraints.  You seem to be suggesting how to modify an existing data set.

Comment: Ohh I missed that you weren't simply trying to filter existing data.  I'm on mobile now.  I'll look at it later it shouldn't be tough to modify it.

Comment: @MarkMiller not much changed except to start with `expand.grid` and then filter it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that creates the desired data set for this specific example.  I suspect the code can be generalized.  If I succeed in generalizing it I will post the result.  Although the code is messy and not intuitive I am convinced there is a basic general pattern.

```
desired.data <- read.table(text = '

     x1  x2  x3  x4
      1   1   1   1
      1   1   1   2
      1   1   1   3
      1   1   2   1
      1   1   2   2
      1   1   2   3
      1   1   3   3
      1   2   1   1
      1   2   1   2
      1   2   1   3
      1   2   2   1
      1   2   2   2
      1   2   2   3
      1   2   3   3
      1   3   3   3
      0   1   1   1
      0   1   1   2
      0   1   1   3
      0   1   2   1
      0   1   2   2
      0   1   2   3
      0   1   3   3
      0   0   1   1
      0   0   1   2
      0   0   1   3
      0   0   0   1
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')

n <- 3   # non-zero numbers
m <- 4-2 # number of middle columns

x1 <- rep(1:0, c(((n*(n-1)) * (n-1) + n), (n*(n-1) + n + (n-1))))
x2 <- rep(c(1:n, 1:0), c(n*m+1, n*m+1, 1, n*m+1, n*1+1))
x3 <- rep(c(rep(1:n, n-1), n, 1:n, 1:0), c(rep(c(n,n,1), n-1), 1, n,n,1, n,1))
x4 <- c(rep(c(rep(1:n, (n-1)), n), (n-1)), n, rep(1:n,(n-1)), n, 1:n, 1)

my.data <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4)

all.equal(desired.data, my.data)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `expand.grid` to generate all combinations and then subset it, one constraint at a time:

```
x<-expand.grid(0:1,0:3,0:3,1:3)

## Once a non-0 appears in a row the rest of that row cannot contain another 0
b1<-apply(x,1,function(z) min(diff(z!=0))==0)
x<-x[b1,]

## Once a 3 appears in a row the rest of that row must only contain 3's
b1<-apply(x,1,function(z) min(diff(z==3))==0)
x<-x[b1,]

## The first non-0 number in a row must be a 1
b1<-apply(x,1,function(z) {
    w<-which(z==0)
    length(w)==0 || z[tail(w,1)+1]==1
})
x<-x[b1,]
```

And now sort it:

```
x<-x[order(x[,1],x[,2],x[,3],x[,4]),]
x
```

Output:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1     0    0    0    1
9     0    0    1    1
41    0    0    1    2
73    0    0    1    3
11    0    1    1    1
43    0    1    1    2
75    0    1    1    3
19    0    1    2    1
51    0    1    2    2
83    0    1    2    3
91    0    1    3    3
12    1    1    1    1
44    1    1    1    2
76    1    1    1    3
20    1    1    2    1
52    1    1    2    2
84    1    1    2    3
92    1    1    3    3
14    1    2    1    1
46    1    2    1    2
78    1    2    1    3
22    1    2    2    1
54    1    2    2    2
86    1    2    2    3
94    1    2    3    3
96    1    3    3    3
```

Comment: Thanks, but that approach does not work well when the number of columns is more than perhaps eight or the numbers to consider range from 0:7 instead of 0:3.  In those cases the approach I use in the original post is much better.